# "ModuleNotFoundError" when importing my own classes

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have 2 files, both are in the same folder.
The file that I am trying to import is "HelloWorldClass.py"
(Code to HelloWorldClass.py)

```py
class HelloWorld():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

and the file that I am calling "HelloWorldClass" from is "ClassTest.py"
(Code to ClassTest.py)

```py
from Classes import HelloWorldClass

HelloWorld()
```

and for some reason, I am getting this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Coding file/Owl Hoot/Classes/ClassTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Classes import HelloWorldClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Classes'
>>>
```

Both files are in the Classes file. I don't see what I am doing wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: I imagine that you mean that Classes is a directory rather than a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both are in the same directory you can import like that:

```
from HelloWorldClass import HelloWorld
```

Comment: Just a question, say the class I wanted to import was in a file in Classes\TestFolder, how would I import it then?

Comment: Let's say the HelloWorldClass file is inside classes folder. You can import this way:
```
from classes.HelloWorldClass import HelloWorld
```
But you need to create an empty file named __init__.py inside classes directory so python recognizes it as a module.
```
touch classes/__init__.py
```